# django - pagination error when sorted by foreignkey

Tags: django

I get a pagination error when I sort by a foreign key field - it sorts the first page just fine, but when I try to go to any other page, an error is displayed: 'invalid column name locationcode'. I understand it is trying to sort the second page by a field that doesn't exist; I want to know how to fix it.

### models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    locationid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column=u'LocationID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column=u'Name')
    def location_code(self):
        return self.locationdetail.locationcode
        location_code.admin_order_field = 'locationdetail__locationcode'
        location_code.short_description = 'Location Code'

class Locationdetail(models.Model):
    locationid = models.OneToOneField('Location',primary_key=True, db_column=u'LocationID')
    glcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'GLCode')
    locationcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column=u'LocationCode')
```

### admin.py

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["location_code", "name",]
    list_display_links = ('location_code','name',)
```

Comment: You didnt say for which model is this class used, but there's used a column `name` so I guess it's for the model `Location`, right? The error says is - there is no **column** locationcode. If you want to order by a foreign key, then you have to use *dunder* notation as everywhere else, ie. 'locationdetail__locationcode' (not sure if it's possible to order by foreignkey in admin tho)

Answer (score 0):

You might be best served by changing your model schema.  It does not appear to me that you are doing anything in your Locationdetail class that would require the information being stored in a separate model.  If you are doing this to make forms render more easily, you may like to merge these models and sort out any logic in the view.  This will give you greater control over pagination and object ordering.